# How to set any jQuery chart data with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts

I'm using a template with jQuery charts [image]
The values in these charts are being set by jQuery but I want to fetch my own values from a database and set them instead of these values that jQuery sets it with. As you know it is not possible to nest PHP in jQuery, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use the [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) library.

I'd suggest you to echo out the javascript part, something like this:

```
<?php
  if($condition){
  echo "<script>
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut',
            resize: true,
            data: [";
    foreach($value as $m){ //Your foreach here with $value you got from fetching data from a database via mysqli or PDO
      $c = count($value);
      $amount = $m['amount']; //just some example things
      if($c != 1){
        echo "{label: '".$type."', value: $amount"."},";
      } else {
        echo "{label: '".$type."', value: $amount"."}";
      }
      unset($value['0']);
    }
      echo" ]
      });
    </script>";
  } else {
    echo "<script>
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut',
            resize: true,
            data: [{label: 'Nothing here yet', value: 1}]
      });
    </script>";
  }
  ?>
```